# Hiding the widget meta box in the Appearance->Widget screen

Tags: widgets, metabox, admin-menu

I don't want to unregister_widget() the widget on the screen, rather, just hide them for admins. Any ideas? I tried: remove_meta_box('widget-id', 'widgets'); but I couldn't figure out the second argument - the screen/page that the widget is displaying on because I can't find the id of the widgets screen

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should already be the case, non-administrators do not have access to the 'Appearance' menu by default.

Here is a list of each role and their capabilities:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

---

Okay so if you want to hide it for everyone, remove_meta_box() won't work because it's not a meta box as far as I can tell from looking at the source.

So alternatively what you could do is:

1. Remove the menu item using `remove_submenu_page('themes.php','widgets.php');` however the page would still be accessible to admins if they just type in the correct url.
2. Use css to hide the widget. Use `admin_enqueue_scripts` to set that up.

Comment: Fair enough. I want it to be hidden for admins as well

Comment: Okay updated my answer

Comment: ah that's a good idea to use CSS.. I was not thinking hah. Although is this just a workaround?

Comment: Yeah a bit of a workaround, this situation is a bit odd. Normally if you don't want someone to have access to widgets, you wouldn't make them an admin.